# addObject for NSMutableArray crashes!

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsmutablearray, sigabrt

I am dealing with a problem which is driving me mad. I have looked at other forums and my code seems to be ok, however it fails when invoking addObject method for NSMutableArray. I am implementing a simple xml parser class and storing some of the information in a NSMutableArray:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Image"]){
          [images setObject: [[imageFile copy] autorelease]  forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: imageId]];
          return;
      }

      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Annotation"]){
          //Here create the annotation object
          Annotation *newAnnot = [[Annotation alloc] init];
          newAnnot.imageId = imageId;
          newAnnot.annDescription = [[annDescription copy] autorelease];
          newAnnot.annLocation = [[annLocation copy] autorelease];
          [annotations addObject: newAnnot];
          [newAnnot release];
          return;
      }

    if([elementName isEqualToString: @"Patient"] || [elementName isEqualToString: @"Images"] || [elementName isEqualToString: @"Annotations"]){
        [currentSection setString: @""]; 
    }else {
        [currentElement setString: @""];
    }


}
```

[annotations addObject: newAnnot] is making the application to receive a SIGABRT signal!

```
2010-11-08 17:15:00.786 Touches[1430:207] *** -[NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b1bb50 2010-11-08 17:15:00.788 Touches[1430:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b1bb50' 2010-11-08 17:15:00.789 Touches[1430:207] Stack: (
    42174544,
    43332396,
    42183259,
    41645686,
    41642482,
    18858,
    39384333,
    70873863,
    70897681,
    39381417,
    17100,
    8863,
    2234926,
    38538931,
    38537114,
    2234111,
    38538931,
    38544407,
    38545466,
    38538931,
    38537114,
    2230794,
    2239193,
    103026,
    108372,
    134462,
    115959,
    147928,
    44216700,
    41453724,
    41449640,
    107041,
    140146,
    8296 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException' Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”. (gdb) continue Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Here a brief description of the code:

Annotation is a simple class derived from NSObject. I am implementing init and dealloc methods. The first one does nothing, just returns "self" whereas dealloc invokes parent and releases the 2 strings

```
@interface Annotation : NSObject {
    int imageId;
    NSString *annDescription;
    NSString *annLocation;
} 

@property (nonatomic, assign) int imageId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *annDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *annLocation;
```

Nothing strange until here. Then have a look at the class implementing the parsing:

```
@interface PatientBundle : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    //............
    NSMutableArray *annotations;
    //.............
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *annotations;
```

My init method looks like this:

```
- (id) initFromFile: (NSString*)pathToFile{
    //.....
    annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 10];
    [addressParser setDelegate:self];
    //......
}
```

Debugging suggests the object I am adding into the "annotations" array is not nil, however I am unable to even insert the first one. Why do I get a NSInvalidArgumentException? Why NSCFDictionary :addObject if my array is of class NSMutableArray? Is anything about the use of NSMutableArray that I am missing?

My platform details:
- Running iphone Simulator Version 4.1 (225)
- Base SDK and deployment target: iOSDevice 4.1 (target IPAD)
- GCC 4.2

Any clue will be kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Luis

Comment: Whatever's going on isn't visible from the code you've posted. Somehow `annotations` is an NSDictionary instead of an array; most likely the pointer is getting overwritten.

Comment: Your annotations property is read/write, not readonly as I would expect it for a mutableArray that is created in the init of the class. Why? Maybe you accidentally call the setter somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`Unrecognized selector sent to <blah>` almost always means that the object in question was released, and another object (of a different type) was later allocated using the same storage.

To track this down, look into [setting NSZombieEnabled](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html), which keeps all freed objects around as "zombies" instead of actually freeing the memory.

Answer (score 2):

The error shows that the object you're sending addObject: to is an NSDictionary. (Remember that the actual class of an object can differ from how you've declared it, even if things are working.) This could happen if you have a stale pointer -- try NSZombieEnabled to track that one.

As a callback, it's even possible that your PatientBundle is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

John's comment is worth looking into. Do a project-wide find for all occurrences of "annotations". Also, use the debugger to ensure that the line you think it's stopping on is really the right one.

Also: I have had weird behavior in my apps when I refer to a property P as plain P instead of self.P. I think you should go through your code and make this change.

Just saw David's comment, which I think is connected with my comment. Plain P does not do the retain; self.P does. Fix this and your troubles may be over.